# How to hash a variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

This example works fine [example](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/hashlib.html):

```
import hashlib
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(b"Nobody inspects")
r= m.digest()
print(r)
```

Now, I want to do the same thing but with a variable: `var= "hash me this text, please"`. How could I do it following the same logic of the example ?

Comment: Have you tried `m.update(var)`?

Comment: @tobias_k: that'll give an error; that's not a bytes value.

Comment: @tobias_k No, I tried `m.update(var)` but i got an error

Comment: For future reference: not everyone knows that `hash.update()` needs bytes and that therefor your problem was that you got an exception when you tried to use a `str` value instead. Next time *include that exception* in your question.

Comment: Thought so (sounded much too easy) but when I tried it worked and I got the same hashcode... tested on Python 2.7, though, not on 3

Comment: @tobias_k: But that is a crucial difference; Python 3 is built on a clear distinction between Unicode and bytes from the ground up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`hash.update()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.update) requires *bytes*, always.

Encode unicode text to bytes first; what you encode *to* is a application decision, but if all you want to do is fingerprint text for then UTF-8 is a great choice:

```
m.update(var.encode('utf8'))
```

The exception you get when you don't is quite clear however:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.md5().update('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

If you are getting the hash of a *file*, open the file in binary mode instead:

```
from functools import partial

hash = hashlib.md5()
with open(filename, 'rb') as binfile:
    for chunk in iter(binfile, partial(binfile.read, 2048)):
        hash.update(chunk)
print hash.hexdigest()
```

Comment: I followed the link you gave me and read about `digest()` method: can it receive a very long phrase ? I mean, if my variable above is the content of a text file (which is the case already), and my text file contains a lot of text, will `digest()` accept such a big file content ?

Comment: @begueradj: yes, it can take anything that fits in Python. If you are reading a text file, you can call `.digest()` multiple times, each time with a next chunk. Loop over the file to get lines, pass each line to `.digest()`, and when the file is done get the digest.

Comment: @begueradj: or you can open the file in *binary* mode and you will not have to encode again.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. Hope it helps.
The variable var has to be utf-8 encoded. If you type in a string i.e. "Donald Duck", the var variable will be b'Donald Duck'. You can then hash the string with hexdigest()

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import hashlib
var = input('Input string: ').encode('utf-8')
hashed_var = hashlib.md5(var).hexdigest()
print(hashed_var)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as the OP. I couldn't get either of the previous answers to work for me for some reason, but a combination of both helped come to this solution.

I was originally hashing a string like this;

```
str = hashlib.sha256(b'hash this text')
text_hashed = str.hexdigest()
print(text_hashed)
```

Result;`d3dba6081b7f171ec5fa4687182b269c0b46e77a78611ad268182d8a8c245b40`

My solution to hash a variable;

```
text = 'hash this text'
str = hashlib.sha256(text.encode('utf-8'))
text_hashed = str.hexdigest()
print(text_hashed)
```

Result; `d3dba6081b7f171ec5fa4687182b269c0b46e77a78611ad268182d8a8c245b40`