# Calculate hash of object , python

Tags: python, python-3.x, blockchain, hashlib

I have a class with string data, and I'm supposed to calculate hash of the whole object using `hashlib.sha256()` . 
I was not directly able to get hash with 
block c for example

```
Hash = hashlib.sha256(c.encode()).digest()
```

I want to calculate hash of the whole object,I was suggested to have a function in the class such that it returns hash of data inside it . Is it same as has of whole block ? What is better implementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hash a variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905062/how-to-hash-a-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement the magic method [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) for your class. You may then use an instance of your class, for example, as a key of a dictionary. Also, if you just need to get a hash, you can simply use the built-in function `hash()`:

```
   c = MyClass()
   c_hash = hash(c)
```

Answer (score 2):

The current answer let's it appear as if there was a need to define `__hash__`. As a partly answer, I hence clarify that this is logically false.

One should be able to implement sha256 or the python interpreter such that of a given class object the full hash is taken.

Reason: With pickle dumps it is possible to save an object uniquely to file. The data footprint of that file is digestable; thus it is a mere insufficiency of the language and should be fixable through some boilerplate code.